# How big should tab bar icons be?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've created an icon that I want to use for a tabbar image. I'm not sure but I believe the icons can be no larger than 75x75.  My icon is 60x64.

When I selected the icon, it is too big for the tabbar button. It hides the button text and much of the icon is clipped. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be around 25x25 points (not pixels) and not more than 48x32 points. So, in pixels:

- **@1x: 25x25** (max: 48x32)
- **@2x: 50x50** (max: 96x64)
- **@3x: 75x75** (max: 144x96)

For more details, you can take a look at this matrix from Apple's Doc: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html